# MOS Test MS Excel 2013 Formula COUNTIF

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, countif

Today I was giving MOS Test for Excel 2013 and I gone through a formula COUNTIF. But the range of formula was specified in very strange way and I did not understand how to select the range. I am posting the picture below, kindly if any one know how to select range in that case, tell me. Range is specified as `RangeNames` but in any of the sheet, there is not cell containing this word. I would be thankful if anybody help regarding this confusion.

**Picture:**

[image]

Comment: Range Name is nothing strange but is the NAME given by the user to the Data Range. Some where we may call it NAMED RANGE. You can perform it by selecting a Data Range, then go to FORMULA TAB, you find Defined Names, has options like, Name Manager, Define Name, Create From Selection.

Comment: @RajeshS thank you buddy, issue has been solved.

Comment: In your case the Formula Should, =COUNTIF(Mountain,"San Juan Peak"). Where Mountain is the NAME given to the Data Range for example C2:C200. If You don't want to use the Range Name then your Formula should, = COUNTIF(C2:C200, "San Juan Peak").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cell range can be specified as A1:B40, but that range can be given a name ie “mountains” and used in any function as relevant.

See the insert menu : names and define...